# Solving $b=a e^{i\phi}\tan\frac\theta2$, $|a^2|+|b^2|=1$ for $a$ and $b$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the following equations,

$$
b=a e^{i\phi}\tan\frac\theta2 \\
|a^2| + |b^2| =1
$$

where I know a (the?) solution to be

$$\begin{align}
a &= \phantom{e^{i\phi}}\cos\frac\theta2 \\[4pt]
b &= e^{i\phi}\sin\frac\theta2
\end{align}$$

Could I have a hint as to what trig identity is needed to find this solution myself?

Comment: Since $|a^2|+|b^2|=1$, it makes sense to say $a=p\cos\psi$ and $b=q\sin\psi$ for some $p$ and $q$ with $|p|=|q|=1$. Substituting into the first equation fairly readily suggests the given solution (but that solution is not unique).

Answer (score 1):

The following identities were used:
$$\tan(\theta/2)=\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos(\theta/2)}\\\sin^2(\theta/2)+\cos^2(\theta/2)=1\\|e^{i\phi}|=1$$
The solution is not unique. Multiplying both $a$ and $b$ by $e^{i\alpha}$ will also give a solution. So using $e^{i\alpha}=e^{-i\phi/2}$ would yield
$$a=e^{-\frac{i\phi}2}\cos\frac{\theta}2\\b=e^{+\frac{i\phi}2}\sin\frac{\theta}2$$